# Android image placed too far from top edge

Tags: android

This is what I want to achieve.

[image: What I want to achieve]

This is what the layout file contains.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:background="@drawable/woodentile" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/innoluck"            
            android:src="@drawable/inno_luck_logo" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/name_user" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name_input"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="22"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/woodenshadowtile" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/papertile" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is what I ended up getting.

[image: what I ended up getting]

How can I change my layout file so that the image view gets closer to the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `View` instead of `ImageView` and it worked.

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/inno_luck_logo"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="162dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/inno_luck_logo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity" >

 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/woodentile" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/innoluck"            
            android:src="@drawable/inno_luck_logo" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/name_user" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name_input"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="22"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/woodenshadowtile" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/papertile" >
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```